# Can I use an ATX power supply to power a graphics card, the USB3380EVB and a Pi?

Tags: alternative-power

I am going to plug a GT4640 using the [USB3380EVB](http://www.hwtools.net/Adapter/USB3380EVB.html). This board connects to the USB slot of the Pi.

> The USB3380EVB has his own power supply which provide energy to the GT640.

I am concern about power issues. I don't know if I will need some security in order to connect this.

Comment: Please add what kind of device is it. A link or model number.

Comment: What does that do? It not for an extra monitor? Because one side is MiniPCI and the other USB3.0/2.0 - So what is it for? Just curios. Are you hacking the GT460 into this? If so then USB2.0 will be tooo slow! You will need to power all the devices usign ATX and just connect the USB to the Pi for data linking.

Comment: i just want to use GPU core advantages. Not need real time aplications.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you will want a separate USB Powered HUB with its own power adapter, in your case an ATX power supply. This is a good power supply for 3v,5v and 12v as its clean and does not suffer from voltage droppage on loads and peaks.

> Make sure to use the 5volt (RED) cables only on the Pi and ideally
>   keep the phase separate, meaning power the Pi from one cable and the
>   HUB from another cable strand.

If they are simple VGA 2D cards only they will usually work of the Pi but as mentioned before you don't want to overload the Pi. 3D devices will have separate power connections. Theoretically you should not use more than 2.5Watts per USB port off the Pi (5v * 0.5A)

Comment: You says that i have to connect the GPU, USB HUB and the Pi to the ATX, then uses the HUB to connect the GPU through the interface ?

Answer (score 0):

The safest bet would be to not plug it into the Pi at all and instead plug it into an externally powered USB hub.  GPU's can draw a large current and might make your Pi unstable depending on the power adapter you have it plugged into.

Comment: What do you mean not plug it into the Pi at all?. I'm planning to use a atx power supply.

Comment: Some, but not all, powered hubs are not isolated on the host side. So the 5v is fed from the hub to the Pi via the usb socket.

Comment: The idea is to connect the ATX to the Pi and the USB3380 board (the board is going to energy the Graphic card). Is this configuration cause any problem ?